# Automatic Bold an active concatenated cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm not sure if what I need can be done by formulas or with a macro.
I tried using conditional formulas to change part of a concatenated text to bold, but it did not work.

For instance, I have a table with 4 columns from `A1:D1`.
The titles are:

```
Name | Age | Gender | concatenate
```

Now there is a lot of information under the first 3 columns and I'm trying to concatenate that info - in example `=concatenate(A2,B2,C2)` - but I need to automatically set the age in bold after entering the formula on `D2`

I'm trying to this for every row that has data under column A-B and C.
I have been looking on the internet, but I did not find any way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

This makes `age` part bold:

```
Private Sub Concatenate()
    Range("A2").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Font.Bold = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ActiveCell.Value & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Characters(Len(ActiveCell.Value) + 1, len(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)).Font.Bold = True 
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

......

This makes `name` bold.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Characters(1, len(ActiveCell.Value)).Font.Bold = True
```

The paranthesis after `.Character` determines the bold part of the text: The part before the comma is the starting location, and the part after the comma is the length of the bold part. `Len(ActiveCell.Value)` is the length of the text in the first column so the bold part starts from the first caharacter and extends to the length of the `name`.

Comment: I tried but actually that one does not change to bold the name it changes to bold the Gender how can I modify it to change the name or the age ?

Comment: what information I need to change on the Macro to get on bold the Name because on this one is giving me the age . I have tried to change the range or the offset values but it does not work

Comment: Explained in the answer.